# Can I use a .select(&) method here?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing some methods for an Artist class, one finds the songs that belong to the artist and the other finds the genres through the songs. I recently found out about the `songs.map(&:genre)` syntax as opposed to writing `songs.map { |song| song.genre }` and it got me a little curious if I could use the same styling for my songs method.

```
   def songs
        Song.all.select { |song| song.artist == self}
    end
    def genres
        songs.map(&:genre)
    end
```

Comment: Maybe. It depends on what Song#all returns, and what you expect to happen if a song is nil or doesn't `respond_to? :artist`.

Comment: Just an aside, this is probably better to do as an activerecord association if you're able (e.g. using a foreign key and has_many/belongs_to)

Comment: Is this for pure Ruby or is it a Ruby&Rails app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unary ampersand in block position simply calls `to_proc` on whatever object it's given. [`Symbol#to_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) produces exactly what you just described; it creates a Proc which takes a single argument and calls the method with the given symbol on it, so `:genre.to_proc` is a procedure which calls the `genre` method on an arbitrary object.

The built-in `Symbol#to_proc` is insufficient to do what you're doing for `songs`; you want to access something and compare it. But, of course, `to_proc` can do whatever we want, so we could make a class that does this.

```
class MatchesArtist
  attr_reader :artist

  def initialize(artist)
    @artist = artist
  end

  def to_proc
    Proc.new { |song| song.artist == self.artist }
  end
end

def songs
  matches = MatchesArtist.new(self)
  Song.all.select(&:matches)
end
```

Now, this can be useful in general, if you're building up combinators using some kind of query language. But for the code you've shown, it's likely that an explicit block is much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a whole class with a `#to_proc` for this, you can just write a method that returns lambda:

```
def matches_artist
  ->(song) { song.artist == artist }
end
```

and then say:

```
Song.all.select(&matches_artist)
```

Or even nicer (IMO):

```
def matches(artist)
  ->(song) { song.artist == artist }
end
```

and say:

```
Song.all.select(&matches(artist))
```

Or even a lambda that returns a lambda:

```
matches = ->(artist) { ->(song) { song.artist == artist } }
Song.all.select(&matches[artist]))
```

Comment: What does the -> do in your example, or are you just using that for notation?

Comment: @ChipLempke The `->` is a "stabby lambda", `->(x) { ... }` is more or less equivalent to `lambda { |x| ... }` which is similar to `proc { |x| ... }`, the differences don't first inside a comment but some googling for "ruby proc vs lambda" should help. Essentially it is a way of making an actual function in Ruby.